# The virtual env doesn't works as expected (env created from python installed from source)

Tags: python, linux

I installed python 3.9.5 from source.

```
mkdir /projects/python
cd /tmp/Python3.9.5
./configure --prefix=/projects/python && make
make install
```

From it I created a virtual environment.

```
virtualenv --python=/projects/python <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

Virtual environment can be activated, running python from environment with builtins works, but packages are installed on the OS python.

I believe the virtual environment is activated because I run `./activate` in environment folder and the prompt is changed `(name_virtual_env)normal_prompt`

`which python` and `pip version` returns:

```
usr/bin/python
usr/bin/pip
```

not the versions from the virtual environment.

Comment: Did you activate it ie : `source <path/to/new/virtualenv/>/bin/activate` ?

Comment: @azro yes, like I said if I execute it is the correct version and built-ins work

Comment: If `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`, they you aren't operating in your virtual environment. A virtual environment isn't "global", it's unique to the shell session in which you used `source <path>/bin/activate`.

Comment: (A virtual environment is very little more than adding your virtual environment's `bin` directory to your `PATH` variable and setting `PYTHONPATH` to refer to the virtual environment's library directory.)

Comment: In fact, you can use `/projects/python` without ever activating it, simply by using `<path>/bin/python` instead of modifying your `PATH` to make `python` alone resolve to `<path>/bin/python`.

Comment: @chepner I added more info to explain why I believe the environment is activated, even if "which" command doesn't see it

Comment: You *must* use `source`; otherwise you are simply activating the virtual environment in a subprocess that immediately exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtualenv` you used may be for the previous python installed.

try :

```
/projects/python/bin/python3 -m pip install virtualenv
/projects/python/bin/virtualenv <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

Comment: if I run the python that is inside the virtual environment return the correct version 3.9.5

Comment: it is working, thanks, seems that even if I passed to virtualenv what python to used, because I was probably using the os one failed to properly link